# How to coerce all elements withing the enviroment to dataframe?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose my environment had only two objects, `df` and `df1`, created as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(mtcars)
df1 <- as_tibble(mtcars)
```

Meaning that when running

```
objects()
[1] "df"  "df1"
```

I would like to coerce all the elements from `objects()` to `data.frame` (or to keep the class `data.frame` only, if that makes more sense).

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
walk(objects(), function(x) objects()[objects()==x] <<- as.data.frame(x))
```

Comment: These objects should not be free-floating if you want to iterate over them. Put them into a list when you create them or catch them using `mget` (together with `ls(pattern = ...)`). Then you can do `dfList <- lapply(dfList, as.data.frame)`.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant to do though since would end up with only 1 object, while I meant to keep two separate objects in my env